# jQuery - add automatic div at fixed time intervals

Tags: jquery

I have simple question: I want to add a new div to the page on a fixed interval (e.g. 5 seconds).

Picture to show what I mean:

[image]

I using for the contents : http://feed2js.org/ but it doen't work, my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   news = $('.rss-item')
   current = 0;
   news.hide();
   Rotator();
});  

function Rotator() {
    $(news[current]).show('slow').delay(300).fadeOut('slow');
    $(news[current]).queue(function() {
        current = current < news.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 1;
        Rotator();
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
}
```

thank you/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need to do something with `setInterval();`

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    news = $('.rss-item')
    current = 0;
    news.hide();

    setInterval(showNewFeed,5000);

    function showNewFeed(){
        if(news.length > 0){
            if(news.filter(':visible').length == 0){
                news.eq(current).fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else{
                news.eq((current - 1)).fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    if(current > news.length){
                        current = 0;
                    }
                    news.eq(current).fadeIn('slow');
                });
            }
        }

        current++;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but it didn't work it just add new div, I need to add more rss-item div...

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't fit your needs. My intent was to show you an idea of how you can set a 5 second interval to call a function. It is up to you to apply it to your situation.

Comment: I tried to up my needs but it didn't work, it just show the whole rss-news. The code: var i = 1;
setInterval(coolFunc,5000); // <-- time in milliseconds. 5000 = 5 seconds

function coolFunc(){
    $('.rss-item').prepend('<div class="rss-item">'+i+'</div>');

    i++;
}

Comment: I have never used `feed2.js` before. If you can post the HTML that it produces then I might be able to provide a more beneficial answer.

Comment: feed2js is rss feeder for website (it showes news from rss to your website) I dont have spacial html code:
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Frss.walla.co.il%2F%3Fw%3D%2F3%2F157%2F1%2F%40rss&num=3&targ=y&utf=y&css=walla_rss&html=a"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>

<noscript>
<a href="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Frss.walla.co.il%2F%3Fw%3D%2F3%2F157%2F1%2F%40rss&num=3&targ=y&utf=y&css=walla_rss&html=y">View RSS feed</a>
</noscript>
it is more java code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval to add new div after every 5 seconds

```
   setInterval(add,5000);

   function add(){
        $("#divMain").append("<br/><div id='New'>New</div>");
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but it didn't work, it doesnt add new rss item. it just show the all news..

Answer (score 0):

Ok if I understand well you got all your rss in the var news and you want hide each news and show them with a 5sec delay between.

Other guys give the good answers because your question was about time but there is the code (not tested) you want (I just change what's wrong in the logic of your code)

```
var $news = null, current = 0, timeInterval = 5000;
$(document).ready( function()
{
  $news = $( '.rss-item' );
  $news.each( function( index, $el )
  {
    $el.hide();
  } );
  Rotator();
} );  

function Rotator() {
  //$( $news[ current ] ).show( 'slow' ).delay( 300 ).fadeOut('slow'); // what ?
  $( $news[ current ] ).fadeIn( 500 );

  if ( ++current < $news.length ) // if end of rss stop loop
  {
    setTimeout( function()
    {
      Rotator();
    }, timeInterval );
  }
}
```

Please guys do not use setInterval

Comment: yes, I want to show every var news, my question wasn't about time.
your code didn't worked, it didnt move and show all the news.

Comment: of course this don't move there is no animation, you should use CSS to animate your rss-item.
If the html is made like I think is it, it should work one by one.
Like MonkeyZeus if you can give us the html code between the parent rss tag (containing all rss-items) should help

Comment: this is the html code:
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Frss.walla.co.il%2F%3Fw%3D%2F3%2F157%2F1%2F%40rss&num=3&targ=y&utf=y&css=walla_rss&html=a"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>

<noscript>
<a href="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Frss.walla.co.il%2F%3Fw%3D%2F3%2F157%2F1%2F%40rss&num=3&targ=y&utf=y&css=walla_rss&html=y">View RSS feed</a>
</noscript>


I meant that I want every only one var news will show and after that 
the next news (only one) but your code didnt do that